# How to print out content-security-policy

Tags: bash, curl

I have tried this command

```
curl -Ik https://dev.mydomain.com/
```

and it does print everything. And now what I want is to print out **content-security-policy** only.

Do I need to use jq or is there any other helpful tool that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl  -sIk https://stackoverflow.com/ | grep content-security-policy | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

Will `curl` the `url`, `grep` only the line with `content-security-policy`, `cut` on a space, and get all the fields from 2 onwards.

---

Example:

```
➜  ~ curl  -sIk https://stackoverflow.com/ | grep content-secur | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://stackexchange.com
```

Comment: Also `curl -sIk https://stackoverflow.com/ | sed -nE 's/content-security-policy: (.*)/\1/ip'`. Parsing headers this way, does not work with multi-line header values, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you use cURL >= 7.84.0, you can use the syntax `%header{name}` :

```bash
curl -Iks https://stackoverflow.com -o /dev/null -w "%header{content-security-policy}"
```

If you want to try it without installing a new version, you can run the Docker image :

```bash
docker run --rm curlimages/curl:7.85.0 -Iks https://stackoverflow.com -o /dev/null -w "%header{content-security-policy}"
```